# Red circle before Contact FullName in Advanced Find (Dynamics CRM 2011)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

The client asked me a question - what is the red circle before the full_name in the advanced find results window (see screenshot below)?

Does anyone know what could it be or at least how to reproduce it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I know what it is.

If you have a `Contact` with the `email address` then the crm will show the status of contact as online/offline

1. Add email address to a contact and you will see this icon.
2. Save and then find that contact you will see red circle.
3. Mouseover the circle and it will show details Presence Unkown/Available.

**Ok If you want to Reproduce it...**

[image]

**In Administration Click System Settings**

**Set the IM presence option to Yes It will re-apppear**

Comment: in my case this circle is already gone... but the email still in place.. how I can reproduce this?

Comment: @Andrey Check how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm rather sure that your client has installed Lync (or Live Messenger, which does not really exist anymore) and he has enabled the presence indicator.

Comment: (+1) You was first, but @Junior gave a more complete answer